# NAS & Torrenting

Tags: hardware, kodi, setup, server, headless

I have a 512MB Pi, Wifi dongle, 1TB Lacie External HDD, 16GB USB Stick, Couple of SD Cards (mostly 10 class), USB 2.0 Self Powered USB Hub etc.

I would like to control my Pi using Macbook which has XBMC setup on it and an android phone.

I would like to **create a NAS & a Torrenting Server** (transmission, couchpotato, showrss, sickbeard etc.) to fully automate access to my media.

---

**Question 1**: Am I able to run both NAS & Torrenting Activities simultaneously on the Pi and if not can I schedule them on a single setup for superior performance?

**Question 2**: I am in the market for a new hard disk drive since my 1TB hdd seems to be always full. To maximize my perceived value I am thinking of getting a 2TB or 3TB External HDD. I am wondering what are your thoughts on my future purchase considering creating one's own cloud also seems like a good project?

I am not looking for long explanations just thoughts and ideas on how to save money on and maximise value of a fully automated media station.

Kindly share your findings. Thank you!!

PS: *What are my chances of using free usenet nzb services if there are any in comparison to torrenting?*

Comment: Q1: yes, you can run Samba, FTP, SSH, AFP and a torrent client at the same time, but remember: your raspberry runs @700Mhz - you may face slow response when too many processes are busy. Q2: try it and see if it works for you! I can only say yes, a x TB external HDD will work on the raspberry. PS: I have no idea about usenet.

Comment: You should be able to both torrent and serve files on your pi. I run Samba, SSH and AFP on a single pi. But io will be an issue as well as CPU. I can get about 10Mb/s backing up via rsync and this drops down to 4Mb/s when another transfer is going on.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to get more bang for your baudwidth backing up to the pi and then having the pi backup to the cloud.

I get about 10Mb/s transfer when I back up my laptop to the pi's USB-HD (it is formatted ext3/4) and then have the pi sync to S3 via the s3sync ruby gem. This provides me an encrypted off-site backup for pretty cheap. I pay less than $12 a month to back up three computers, a lot of digital photos, a large mp3 collection and family movies.

I use a modified script based on a blog post about [Using rsync to mimic the behavior of Apple's Time Machine feature](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html) which works on both OSX and Win7. I also use it to backup my android tablet's sd card.

Answer (score 2):

I currently own 2, both 512MB versions. Sickbeard and sabnzb run really slow, loading the ui  takes at least 5 seconds and adding and editing shows in sickbeard is really slow.

Using it for samba, vpn, etc is fine but I find just running sickbeard on its own on a single pi is just not worth it. Also with sabnzb I cannot get my download speed over 1-Mb/sec and when its downloading the load is usually over 12. I've done tests with wget and it'll max out my connection no problem.

Using it for xbmc is great (running raspbmc) and I usually have no issues with watching 1080p video, but I've given up trying to get sickbeard and sabnzb running at a decent speed on a Pi